# How to run Tkinter GUI and Python command line at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

so i have a Chessboard GUI which displays a Chessboard with pieces and a UI which allows users to enter a piece to move. Currently both my GUI and UI are working but when i run the program the UI runs without the GUI. Is there a way i can run the GUI and UI at the same time?

My main Class:

```
class ChessBoard(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, rows=8, columns=8, size=70, color1="white", color2="lightgrey"):

    self.rows = rows
    self.columns = columns
    self.size = size
    self.color1 = color1
    self.color2 = color2
    self.pieces = {}

    canvas_width = columns * size
    canvas_height = rows * size

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="white")
    self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

    color = self.color2
    for row in range(self.rows):
        color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
        for col in range(self.columns):
            x1 = (col * self.size)
            y1 = (row * self.size)
            x2 = x1 + self.size
            y2 = y1 + self.size
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=color, tags="square")
            color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
```

my UI:

```
    def UserInput(self):

            KingRow = int(input("Choose Row: ")) 
            KingColumn = int(input("Choose Column: ")) 

            #Not Complete UI
```

This is where everything is called:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     root = tk.Tk()
     board = ChessBoard(root)
     board.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true", padx=4, pady=4)
     board.UserInput()
     root.mainloop()
```

What ive tried so far is Root.after() but nothing seems to happen (im probably using it wrong)

The only time the GUI runs is when there is an error within the UI.Is there a way i can run the GUI and UI at the same time? thanks!

Comment: You never create a canvas so your program should throw an error.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question. There is not enough of your code to reproduce the problem. Without the MCVE it will be unlikely that you get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Why not use pop up dialog boxes to enter the row/column information rather than having to do it from the command line?

Comment: @Mike-SMT a canvas is being created and there is no error currently present within my code.

Comment: Not from the code you have provided. From what I can see you never created a canvas and I do get errors. `AttributeError: 'ChessBoard' object has no attribute 'canvas'`. You cannot expect people to assume you have created a canvas if you do not provide the code in your example. Cannot troubleshoot what is not there.

Comment: @scotty3785 i just tried a message box and even then, the message box gets displayed first and only after closing the message box the chessboard is displayed.

Comment: @Mike-SMT i have created the canvas:   self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="white"). And i currently get 0 errors at all, maybe you have not imported tkinter? in which case use this:    import tkinter as tk

Comment: Look at the code you have in your question Sharjeel. You do not create a canvas in your question anywhere.

Comment: @Mike-SMT goddamn, i just realised a chunk of my code was missing! so sorry!, the code has now been updated.

Comment: Please note that `board.addpiece()` and `board.new()` refer to non-existent methods in your question. `board.UserInput()` Will fail as `self.KingMoves(KingRow,KingColumn)`also refers to a non existent method in your question.

Comment: @Mike-SMT sure, the code has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely you are using `root.after()` wrong in this case but we cannot tell without the code you have used.

In the `after()` method you will need to pass a a number and a command. The number is representative of milliseconds so 1000 would be 1 second. The command can be a lambda or a link to a method/function. so something like this. `root.after(1000, some_function_name)`.

Your application will freeze anytime you call `input()` as the program must wait for a reply thus pausing the `mainloop()`. This make things more complicated than they need to be and probably wont ever work like you want. You will likely want to move the user input into the GUI instead of using console input.

You can provide an `Entry` field for the user and a button for submitting the info. You can also bind the `<Return>` key the the user can just hit Enter.

I have modified your code to give a basic example of how you can use entry fields, labels, and bindings to provide a place for user input that will not freeze the program like using the console `input()` would.

I changed `pack()` to `grid()` as I find it easier to deal with when setting up a GUI. I have used `.bind()` to set a command for the `UserInput()` method.

This example is simply updating a label but should show you how to use `get()` the user input and then apply it to something.

```
import tkinter as tk


class ChessBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=8, columns=8, size=70, color1="white", color2="lightgrey"):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}

        canvas_width = columns * size
        canvas_height = rows * size

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="white")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")

        self.UI_lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Choose Row: ")
        self.UI_lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e")
        self.UI_entry1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.UI_entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.UI_lbl2 = tk.Label(self, text="Choose Column: ")
        self.UI_lbl2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e")
        self.UI_entry2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.UI_entry2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.UI_entry1.bind("<Return>", self.UserInput)
        self.UI_entry2.bind("<Return>", self.UserInput)

        self.game_lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Player moves: ")
        self.game_lbl.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky="w")

        color = self.color2
        for row in range(self.rows):
            color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
            for col in range(self.columns):
                x1 = (col * self.size)
                y1 = (row * self.size)
                x2 = x1 + self.size
                y2 = y1 + self.size
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=color, tags="square")
                color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2

    def UserInput(self, Event):
        KingRow = self.UI_entry1.get()
        KingColumn = self.UI_entry2.get()
        self.game_lbl.config(text="Player moves Game Piece to Row: {}, Column: {}".format(KingRow, KingColumn))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    board = ChessBoard(root)
    board.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="nsew")
    root.mainloop()
```